# Do I need to standardise variables when computing an index of interest?

Tags: standardization, weighted-data

Suppose I have to create an "index of interest" for the products of an e-commerce. By index of interest I mean a $parameter$ which, based on some variables, tells me which products are the most interesting to my customers. For each product in the e-commerce I have:

- number of $visualizations$;
- number of $clicks$ on the "info" button of the product;
- $time$ spent on the page of the product;
- number of times the product has been added to the $basket$;
- "conversion $rate$", calculated as (number of times the product has been added to the basket) / (number of visualizations)

Now, to create this index of interest I thought I could compute a weighted average, after having decided which weights to assign to each variable. For example:

- number of $visualizations$ [$w_1: 0.05$]
- number of $clicks$ on the "info" button of the product [$w_2: 0.2$]
- $time$ spent on the page of the product [$w_3: 0.15$];
- number of times the product has been added to the $basket$ [$w_4: 0.3$];
- "conversion $rate$", calculated as (number of times the product has been added to the $basket$) / (number of $visualizations)$ [$w_5: 0.3$]

So my $parameter$ could be:
$parameter = visualizations \cdot w_1 + clicks \cdot w_2 + time \cdot w_3 + basket \cdot w_4 + rate \cdot w_5$

Obviously those variables have different scale, so my question is: do I have to standardise those variables? At first I thought it would be normal to standardise, but I'm not too sure. Maybe if I compute a weighted average I already take into account the different importance that each variable has on the final index. Also, if I have to standardise, do I have to standardise also the $rate$? Since it is a ratio maybe I don't need to standardise it.

Comment: I don't buy the premise 'I have to create an "index of interest"' but if that is an instruction, then yes, the calculation would be useless without some standardisation and the weights are not a solution for that, but for a different issue, that you don't regard the variables as of equal importance. But quite what standardisation I leave an open question. I am not a fan of lumping things together like this. Detail: What you are calculating does **not** qualify as a parameter in the statistical sense. It is another variable.

Comment: @NickCox I did not understand what you meant by "I don't buy the premise", maybe it's my language limit. However, do you know other methods by which I can create a parameter that can tell me which products are the most interesting, using those variables?

Comment: I don't understand, or sympathise with, the notion that you _must_ create a composite index. Such measures can be hard to defend and disappointing in practice, as they purport to reduce several measures to one that somehow transcends them.

Comment: A practical note: I personally would use these indicators as separate outcome variables.

Comment: @NickCox I understand your point, but I think that sometimes even if you collect a wide range of different data, it could be useful to try summarising some of them with other composite variables, especially when dealing with people which are not into statistics. I am simulating a situation in which I have someone who asks me to show him which products his customers find more attractive. I am open to other ideas.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any experience with your kind of data to advise more concretely on what you should do. But as a customer like anyone else I can find products attractive or unattractive  in quite different ways and have no interest in collapsing that to a single dimension.  I am puzzled at the idea that non-statistical audiences are sympathetic to composite variables, which doesn't match my impressions. However, this is on the margins of your question, to which there is a simple immediate answer.

Comment: Maybe add the tag [tag:recommender-system] ?